# img-responsive with fixed style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I use a editor to upload photo and resize for my content.
But found an issues.
When a photo resized then img-responsive won't work correctly 
editor will add a style to  tag.

Like this

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/12d79e0f6124c89a380e89d7de0cc37b.jpg" style="width: 351px; height: 557.005px;">
```

When access site from mobile, image not responsive 
I need to keep image size from image resizer (from text editor) 
but still can responsive.

Comment: What text editor for starters?

Comment: please share contents of `img-responsive` class

Comment: you can use jQuery to remove inline height,width of that image on document.ready

Comment: Maybe try to work with `max-width` and `max-height`?

Comment: froala editor. and img-responsive from bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

use this class

```
 .img-responsive{
    width:100% !important;
    }
```